Android Redirection Intent Not Working For Firefox in Angular
I'm trying to use an intent in an Angular Application, and It works just fine for Chrome, but when It tries to run on Firefox, everything breaks, there's not even a log about it.
What am I missing?
component.ts:
url = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(`intent://${this.mountUrl()}#Intent;scheme=https;end`);

component.html
<div *ngIf="isAndroid() && !isIframe">
  <a id="browser-openner"
     [hidden]="true"
     [href]="url">
  </a>
</div>

I tried using
  url = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(`intent://${this.mountUrl()}#Intent;scheme=https;package=org.mozilla.firefox;end`);

I only need to do this for Android specifically
***Update
After more research on it, I was able to make it work by adding: target="_blank" to the  tag. Any thoughts on that? Why chrome works just fine, but firefox is not working accordingly
